# How do I Link to a specific ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, linker, jsx

[image: Overview over my products]

[image: My routing between pages]

[image: My link from Product page to a specific product through specific ID]

My problem right now is that I'm getting id out as a string.

[image]

And I'm not quite sure how it should be set up in my Link in Product.js.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of you code but create actual code snippets as [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Anyway, as per [React Router Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link), you can use `<Link to={{ pathname: "/courses", search: "?sort=name", hash: "#the-hash", state: { fromDashboard: true } }} />`; in your case, you just need to set `pathname` and `hash`

Comment: Thank you but I'm still not sure how to set it up. I get through to a new page, but I dont get any output.

Answer (score 0):

@Mads, Your sandbox is not working and giving an error. I could not find where is your data file, have you added your switch inside the Router(BrowserRouter)? Please give a working code.. how can you even expect an answer without giving the main tree content & component.? You should remove all unnecessary codes and clearly show what problem you are facing, please.

Anyways you can try the below code inside your Project.js file. This will work if you have given/included id inside your data file.

```
  <div className="bg">
    {this.state.data !== undefined
      ? this.state.data.map((product, id) => {
          return (
            <div key={id} className="mainContainer">
              <div className="billedeContainer">
                <Link to={`/details/${id}`}
                >
                  <img src={product.image} alt="produktBillede" />
                </Link>
              </div>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-wu-sl4o2?file=/src/Components/Product.js 

Is this better?